# npm ERROR trying to run a project in Angular

Tags: angular, npm

I'm triying to run my project with `ng serve -o`. The problem is that the following warning appears on the screen:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (15.2.2) is greater than your local version (15.0.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
```

I reinstalled angular with `install -g @angular/cli` and then use `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest` for upgrade my local version but, when I enter the command the following appears:

```
C:\Users\user1\Dropbox\Angular\myApp>npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   jasmine-core@"^3.6.0" from karma-jasmine@4.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/karma-jasmine
npm ERR!     peer karma-jasmine@">=1.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!       dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     dev karma-jasmine@"~4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: jasmine-core@4.5.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!     dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-09T17_09_29_793Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-09T17_09_29_793Z-debug-0.log
```

I don't know what I can do, so please how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: looks like karma-jasmine is out of sync. maybe try npm install of those modules with --force

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error itself:

```bash
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

When you run `npm i`, you need to specify `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` due to peer dependency version mismatches, or you need to create an `.npmrc` file in your project root with:

```bash
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

Once your version mismatches with dependencies are resolved, you won't get this error.

Comment: Doing that and next trying of start the server, nothing happens.

C:\Users\user1\Dropbox\Angular\myApp>ng serve -o

C:\Users\user1\Dropbox\Angular\myApp>

Comment: `ng serve -o` doesn't take any parameters